# VS code debugger does not stop for gorourines

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug inside a function but it won't stop when called as a goroutine. e.g. in the following code, it only stops when the argument num=6. However, I am sure it gets executed twice as it prints 56 or 56 (sometimes only 5 , not sure why probably another sof question.)

```
import "fmt"

func hello(num int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d", num)
}
func main() {
    go hello(6)
    hello(5)
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that this code will print 6 before 5, so printing both is valid, and not printing 6 at all is also perfectly correct. This has nothing to do with the debuger.

Comment: Yes the order isn't guaranteed but this question is about not able to stop during both the calls and sometimes just printing only one number.